# Delete logs that ended with date format

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find

I created the following cli in order to delete the logs with date format that oldest then 500 min

date format is:

```
 data-node.log.xxxx-xx-xx-[1-10]
```

the cli that should removed the logs

```
find /var/log/test/  -type f -mmin +500 -regextype sed -regex '.*\.log\.[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2,10\}$' -delete
```

as we can see the logs still exists

```
ls -l /var/log/test/



-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 10:02 data-node.log.2019-12-14
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 10:02 data-node.log.2019-12-15
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 10:02 data-node.log.2019-06-16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 10:02 data-node.log.2020-01-17
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 10:05 data-node.log.2020-01-1723
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 10:05 data-node.log.2020-01-172334
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 10:05 data-node.log.2020-01-17233434
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 10:05 data-node.log.2020-01-1723343434
```

where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not match the files. Change

`'.*\.log\.[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2,10\}$'`

for

`'.*\.log\.[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2,10\}$'`

since there's no third hyphen (nor fourth date field).

Answer (score 0):

You made two logical errors, while composing your regex:

1.
'.*.log.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} **-** [0-9]{2,10}$
This minus will not exist.

2.
'.*.log.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9] **{2,10}** $
This quantor is wrong. The file names can, but will not necessarily contain 2 upto 10 extra numbers. Therefore the endline $ is wrong, too.

This will work:

```
find /var/log/test/ -type f -mmin +500 -regextype sed -regex '.*\.log\.[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}[0-9]*' -exec rm {} +
```

Exec + will stack the command with as many filenames possible.